# is there an overdraw issue in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, layout

I have to create the following layout in iOS.

[image]

in android we could use a single `EditText` to create this. 
But in iOS we need

1. An imageView for background
2. A text field for the text
3. An image view for search icon

In android this causes overdraw. 
is there the same overdraw issue in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do without following view combination

```
An imageView for background
A text field for the text
An imageView for search icon
```

best possible way is you can loop through the search bar subview and replace or modify the curent subview to create the custom search bar

and there is nothing like over draw because they are key component for drawing a view. if you need any specific clarification then let me know

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `UISearchBar`.

Or `UITextField` with a border (set on its `layer`), `placeholder` text and a rightView (set to an image view) for the icon.